# how to open facebook/gmail/authencation sites using python urllib2.urlopen?

Tags: python, authentication, proxy, urllib2

I am trying to write a small web-based proxy using python, I can fetch and show normal websites, but I can not login to facebook/gmail/...anything with login .
I have seen some examples of authentication here
http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/urllib2-examples.html but I don't know how I can make a general solution for all web sites with login , any idea?

my code is :

```
def showurl():
    url=request.vars.url
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    return html
```

Answer (score 2):

Your proxy-server needs to store cookies, search stackoverflow for cookielib.

Many web sites authenticate clients in different way, so your job is to fake client as much as possible with your proxy-server. Some web sites authenticate by browser type, some by creating cookies and storing sessionId in it, or other JavaScript hidden content that allows to do some authentication steps.
As far as my small experience, all important stuff ends in cookies.

This is just flat example how to use cookielib.

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib, getpass

username = ''
button = 'submit'
www_login = 'http://website.com'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0'))
opener.addheaders.append( ('Referer', '/dev/null') )

login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password': getpass.getpass("Password:"), 'login' : button})
resp = opener.open(www_login, login_data)
print resp.read()
```

EDITED:
Don't mislead yourself with "Basic HTTP Authentication" and authentication by facebook/gmail because it is different stuff. "Basic HTTP Authentication" or "Digest HTTP Authentication" is done by web-server not web-site that you want to log in.

Comment: is there way to make it work for all websites ? so I don't have to enter username and pass for ever single site int he code ? (I want users to be able to login anywebsite they want and enter their own username pass)

Comment: now i understand the question ... it is possible, but i am not sure if there is an easy way to do it, like everything in one function ... http://proxies.xhaus.com/python/ this is list of python proxy projects http://code.google.com/p/proxpy/ ... google "web proxy in python". And i think your problem is https/cookies right now, if you already did simple http proxy. Hope this helps.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html it is 'replacement' for urllib2, making things easier ...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml#id24